# como hacer referencia a varios datos en conn.query

Tags: javascript, mysql

Estoy tratando de obtener e insertar datos a una base de datos a partir de javascript. Me ha resultado bien cuando trato con solo un dato o un solo objeto pero cuando intento con mas de uno no puedo.
En el siguiente código lo que trato de hacer es insertar el dato dentro de "búsqueda" en ambos "?" pero me da error al haber dos de estos.

```
async function getVentasClientemain(busqueda){
    const conn = await getConnection();
    const resultado = await conn.query('select * from venta inner join clientes on clientes.id_cliente = venta.id_cliente where venta.precio like ? or venta.fecha like ? order by venta.fecha DESC', busqueda);
    console.log(resultado);
    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! busqueda tiene un solo dato?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que estás pasando un sólo argumento a la [sentencia preparada](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Prepared-Statements.md):

```js
const resultado = await conn.query('select * from ... where venta.precio like ? or venta.fecha like ? order by venta.fecha DESC', busqueda);
```

En este caso, por cada máscara `?` en tu sentencia se intenta acceder a un argumento diferente en la lista de argumentos, y tú sólo has indicado 1 argumento.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es simple, debes pasar 2 veces el mismo argumento, pero los debes pasar en un Array, ya que el método `query` usará cada elemento de dicho Array de forma posicional, así, el primer elemento corresponde al primer carácter `?` de la sentencia, el segundo elemento corresponde al segundo carácter `?` de la sentencia y así sucesivamente.

Por lo tanto, tu consulta debería verse así:

```js
async function getVentasClientemain(busqueda){
  const conn = await getConnection();
  const resultado = await conn.query(
    'select * from venta inner join clientes on clientes.id_cliente = venta.id_cliente where venta.precio like ? or venta.fecha like ? order by venta.fecha DESC',
    [busqueda, busqueda] // <- Array con ambos valores
  );
  console.log(resultado);
  return resultado;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.